# Magento: get translated String in php

Tags: php, magento

Is it somehow possible to get the translated name of a category in Magento inside the php code? I.e. something like `$category->getTranslatedName`?
Background: I want to sort categories alphabetically, but having different names in different languages this only really works in the english shopview. My code:

```
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $_children[$i]["child"] = $child;
    $_children[$i]["name"] = $child->getName();
    //gets english name, not the translated
    $i++;
}

if (!function_exists('compare')) {
    function compare($a,$b) {
        return strcmp($a["name"],$b["name"]);
    }
}

usort($_children, "compare");

for ($i=0; $i<count($_children); $i++) {
    //code for main menu here
}
```

Edit: here is the part where it loads $children (it is taken from renderer.phtml):

```
$children = $menuTree->getChildren();
$parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
$childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

$counter = 1;
$childrenCount = $children->count();

$parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
$itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

$i = 0;
foreach ($children as $child) {
    $_children[$i]["child"] = $child;
    $_children[$i]["name"] = $child->getName();
    $i++;
}

if (!function_exists('compare')) {
    function compare($a,$b) {
        return strcmp($a["name"],$b["name"]);
    }
}

usort($_children, "compare");

for ($i=0; $i<count($_children); $i++) {
//Code for main menu
}
```

Comment: "Name" is a translatable attribute in Magento, so to retrieve the translated name you need to set the appropriate store ID to the category collection before you load it

Comment: As Robbie said - can you add the code where you load in `$children`

Comment: I wouldn't have considered this...so I can practically specify the storeview while loading $children? I have edited the post to contain the complete code.